# does setup and draw function run parallel in processing

Tags: processing

Does the `fileselected` function in this code complete its execution even before `while` loop execution?

```java
void setup()
{ 
size(800, 600);
selectInput("Select a file to process:", "fileSelected"); 
while(data==null)
{
 delay(1000);
}
 }
 void fileselected()
  {
   *
    *

   *

  *

  }
```

How do I make the draw function wait until it receives the necessary arguments to run?

Comment: Please [debug your program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) and narrow your problem down to a [mcve].

Comment: Im not able to figure out where exactly the issue is. problem could be in the draw() function of proj4.pde.

Comment: That isn't really how Stack Overflow works. Please debug your code. What is the value of every variable on that line? One of them is `null`. Figure out why that is, and post a [mcve] if you're still stuck. Good luck.

Comment: This is now a completely different question than you originally posted?

Comment: Why are you asking us question 1? You should just be able to **test it yourself**.

Answer (score 2):

> does setup and draw function run parallel in processing

No. First the `setup()` function is called and completes, then the `draw()` function is called 60 times per second.

> does the fileselected function completes its execution even before while loop execution.

The `fileSelected()` function will be called when the user selects a file. You really shouldn't call the `delay()` function in a loop like that.

> How do I make the draw function to wait until it receives the necessary arguments to run.

Something like this:

```java
boolean fileLoaded = false;

void setup(){ 
  size(800, 600);
  selectInput("Select a file to process:", "fileSelected"); 
}

void fileSelected(File selection){
  fileLoaded = true;
}

void draw(){
  if(!fileLoaded){
    //short-circuit and stop the function
    return;
  }
}
```

You could go a step further and use the `noLoop()` and `loop()` functions. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).